# How can I have two widgets on one page using the kivy carousel?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a carousel like the following image.

[image]

I need to have two and a half widgets on the page, while kivy carousel displays only one widget at a time. Does anyone have experience with such a thing?

Comment: Have a look at the scrollview widget. It allows for scrolling off and on screen without the granular movement of the carousel widget.